# Can't read frozen Tensorflow graph in OpenCV with UpSampling2D layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

I'm getting the following error when calling `cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('./frozen.pb')` to read a frozen Tensorflow graph containing an UpSampling2D layer (last line in code example):

```
cv_model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('./frozen.pb')
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:2824: error: (-2:Unspecified error) More than one input is Const op in function 'getConstBlob'
```

Here is a python example to reproduce the error. The error occurs on the last line.

```py
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2

# Create model
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input((10, 10, 3)),
    layers.Conv2D(8, 3, activation='elu', padding='same'),
    layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)),
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()

# Freeze model
full_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(
    tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype))
frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(full_model)
frozen_func.graph.as_graph_def()
tf.io.write_graph(frozen_func.graph, './', 'frozen.pb', False)

# read frozen graph with opencv
cv_model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('./frozen.pb') # Error here
```

If the UpSampling2D layer is commented out, the resulting frozen graph can be read successfully by OpenCV.

I have tried running this code on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 and on a range of different OpenCV and Tensorflow versions including the latest. I have also tried loading the model in C++ with OpenCV 4.5.5. In all cases I get the same error message.

Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Isn't  frozen.pb is in currently folder?

Comment: Yes, frozen.pb is in the current folder. The error occurs when I try to read frozen.pb with `cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow`. The error is caused by the UpSampling2D layer in the neural network model. When this layer is removed OpenCV is able to read the frozen.pb without error.